# Configuring a Visual Studio 2013 Database Unit Test project after it has been created

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have created a database unit test project in Visual Studio 2013. I need to change app.config, specifically the test data insertion section, but I can't find how to access the "SQL Server Test Configuration" screen that appears when you create a new project, and I can't find any information about the SqlUnitTesting_VS2013 or DataGeneration XML elements online.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, interesting how do you create a Database Unit Test Project in VS2013. Is there a separate project template?

Comment: Go to View->Sql Servier Project Explorer. Select a stored proc, right click, and select Create Unit Test. After that it is self explanatory.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've added the menu item directly to the menu bar using Tools -> Customise and it shows as disabled nomatter what I click on. I think it might be a bug.